The probability of multiplicity of the sum of the dice
A player has $2$ dice. The player throws them until at least one of the dice has a $6$. They sum the intermediate results. Find the probability of the event that at the end of the game (we add the final toss into the sum) the sum will be a multiple of $3$.
My attempt at a solution:

The probability of getting at least one six on two dice in one roll is $\frac{12}{36}$.

So, on average, we need $\frac{36}{12} = 3$ throws to throw one six.

On average, on one roll, when there is no six, the sum on two dice will be:

$$((1+1)+(2+2)+(3+3)+(4+4)+(5+5))\cdot \frac{2}{36}+\frac{1}{36} \cdot 2\cdot ((1+2)+(1+3)+(1+4)+(1+5)+(2+3)+(2+4)+(2+5)+(3+4)+(3+5)+(4+5)) = \frac{5}{3} + \frac{1}{18} \cdot (18+18+15+9) = \frac{5}{3} + \frac{1}{18} \cdot (18+18+15+9) = \frac{15}{3} = 5$$
that is, the average amount on two dice in a throw without sixes is $5$. And there will be $2$ such throws, they will give an average of $10$ points.

On the last roll, we exactly throw $6$ on one of the dice, and on the other dice we get an average of $\frac{1}{6} \cdot (1+2+3+4+5+6) = 3.5$

The sum on this last roll is $9.5$
Then the total sum is $2\cdot 5 + 9.5 = 19.5$
I doubt my decision and answer, did I calculate the conditional sum correctly in this case? How do I get to the multiplicity of three here?

You mean "sums the intermediate results" not "summarizes".

I would do this by states.  There are only three active states, according to the residue class mod $3$ of the sum so far.   Remember:  we don't care at all what the sum is, we only care about its remainder on division by $3$.

Note;  there is an $\frac {11}{36}$ chance that you get at least one $6$, not $\frac {12}{36}$ as you claim.

Also the rules aren't clear:  do we add the final toss into the sum or not?  This matter if, say, the final toss is ${X,6}$ where $X\in {1,2,4,5}$.

@lulu, yes we add final toss (both dices) into the sum

Then I suggest adding that rule to your post, it's not clear from what you wrote.

@lulu, can you please describe the idea of 3 states in more detail. As far as I understand, these states have different probabilities, but in order to correctly estimate the probabilities, we need to understand how we came to this point (what dices and what steps), but we have an unknown number of steps BEFORE the final state.

No, you don't need the history you only need to know the current state.  The current state is determined by the sum so far and it is one of ${0,1,2}$ as we only care about the remainder on division by $3$.  You start is state $0$, for instance.  Convince yourself that, if you end on the first round, there is a $\frac 3{36}$ chance that you end in state $0$ (in which case you win) and a $\frac 4{36}$ chance that you end in state $1$ (and lose) and a $\frac 4{36}$ chance that you end in state $2$ (and again lose).  Of course, you might not end on the first round.

As a heuristic guide:  since each residue class is equally likely on each toss, you expect the answer to be about $\frac 13$.  Given that you add in the final toss, though, there is a slight bias against ending in state $0$ (illustrated in prior comment).  That means that the answer you seek should be near $\frac 13$ but slightly lower.

It is a Markov chain with 5 states. An "active state" for each remainder $\mod 3$ of the running sum and two ending states indicating whether the final sum is $0 \pmod 3$ or not. I believe we have this transition matrix (states enumerated as actives $0,1,2$ and end states so that the $0 \pmod 3$ is last
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rr}
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{12} \\
\frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{7}{36} & \frac{1}{9} \\
\frac{2}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{7}{36} & \frac{1}{9} \\
\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).
$$
The probabilities of being absorbed to the corresponding end states are given by
$$
\left(\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
-
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{2}{9} \\
\frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{2}{9} \\
\frac{2}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{4}
\end{array}\right) \right)^{-1}
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{2}{9} & \frac{1}{12} \\
\frac{7}{36} & \frac{1}{9} \\
\frac{7}{36} & \frac{1}{9}
\end{array}\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{24}{35} & \frac{11}{35} \\
\frac{23}{35} & \frac{12}{35} \\
\frac{23}{35} & \frac{12}{35}
\end{array}\right).
$$
Since we start from $0$ (the first state), the probability that the final sum is a multiple of $3$ is
$$
\frac{11}{35}.
$$

Sage code to make:
M = 3
D = 6
matN = M+2
a = [[0 for j in range(matN)] for i in range(matN)]
for i in range(M):
    for d1 in range(1,D+1):
        for d2 in range(1,D+1):
            i2 = (i+d1+d2)%M
            if M in (d1,d2):
                i2 = M + (0 if i2%M else 1)
            a[i][i2] += 1/D**2
a[M][M] += 1
a[M+1][M+1] += 1
A = matrix(QQ, a)
A.subdivide(M,M)
show(A)
show(matrix.identity(M), A[:M,:M],  A[:M,M:])
ps = (matrix.identity(M)-A[:M,:M])^(-1) * A[:M,M:]
show(ps)


$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
A|B & 1&2&3&4&5&6 \\ \hline
1&2&0&1&2&0&1\\ \hline
2&0&1&2&0&1&2 \\ \hline
3&1&2&0&1&2&\bf{0} \\ \hline
4&2&0&1&2&0&1 \\ \hline
5&0&1&2&0&1&2 \\ \hline
6&1&2&\bf{0}&1&2&\bf{0} \\ \hline  \end{array}$
The values within the table are (die throw sums)mod $\,3$, and using $a,b.c$ for $(0,1,2)mod3$, and multiplying through by $36$ to clear all fractions, we get the equations
$36a = 9a+8b+8c +3 \tag 1$
$36b = 8a+9b+8c+4 \tag 2$
$36c = 8a+8b+9c+4 \tag 3$
which yields the final answer  $a = \frac{11}{35}$

To explain a bit more, the technique used is First Step Analysis, and perhaps I should write the first equation in full "proper" form
$a = \frac9{36}a +\frac8{36}b + \frac8{36}c + \frac8{36}\times 0 + \frac 3{36}\times 1$
The fractions show the probabilities of moving from one state to another, and since we are counting probability of success, the final movement to success has a $1$ multiplier and that to failure a $0$ multiplier, and since the latter  doesn't add anything, that term has been omitted in the $3$ equations, and the fractions cleared so that you can directly count in the given table

PS:
I must direct users to note the simpler solution  in the comments section by Daniel Mathias, reducing the number of active states to two: 0 mod3 and non-zero mod 3

If the sum is 1 or 2 (mod 3), the probability of winning on the next throw is 4/36. This is not the same as the starting state. Simulation gives a result of approximately 0.3143

The result is exactly $\frac{11}{35}$. I don't have time to post details tonight.

@DanielMathias: Thanks, have amended !

That's what I had, except with $b$ and $c$ combined: $36p=3+9p+16q$ and $36q=4+8p+17q$

@DanielMathias: Ohh, this nice simplification didn't occur to me while solving !
